# How to come up with a math equation from a known set of values

Tags: php, math, equation, integral

I have a table like this:

```
IQ       Score   Percentile 
58.75  |   0   |   0
70     |   15  |   2
85     |   35  |   16
100    |   55  |   50
115    |   75  |   84
130    |   95  |   90
```

Im trying to find an equation that I can use to dynamically generate with PHP the 'Percentile' value when I know both the IQ and the Score.

This table came from an Excel spreadsheet, it might have been calculated with VLOOK or something like that.

Any ideas on how I could calculate those values?

Comment: percentile would be (count where iq < targetiq) / (count of total population) * 100

Comment: So if IQ = 92.5;  Score = 45; what would be the percentile?

Comment: It would be the number of IQ's < 92.5 / the total number IQ's for percential ... replace IQ with score to get percentile ranking for score.

Comment: Is the table much bigger than you're showing?  "Percentile" only makes sense if you have enough data (way more than 6).  How are IQ and score related?  Is IQ a function of score, and so you just need a percentile of scores?

Answer (score 0):

I think the query you are after is

```
  SELECT SUM(IF(IQ < $target_id, 1,0)) *100 / COUNT(IQ) from IQ_TABLE;
```